# How to customize the interval for email setting "Download new content"?

Tags: settings, email

*Settings -> email + account -> select an account*

Under Download new content, I see options normally like as items arrive, 15 mins, 30 mins hourly and manually.

How can I set customized hours like every 2 hours, every 4 hours etc..
I ask this question because on one of my email account settings the option for Download new content are different. 15 mins, 30 mins hourly, every 2 hours and manually.

So what drives these options? Is it possible to set customized hours like every 2 hours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The times are driven by the type of account -- those that support direct push (such as Hotmail, Gmail, Exchange, etc.) get the option to download items "as they arrive". Older style mail servers using the POP3 protocol do not get this option, and instead get the "every 2 hours" option.